# Concurrency issue with CosmosDb

Tags: c#, .net, azure, concurrency, azure-cosmosdb

We are struggling with the duplicate documents getting created due to race condition. We process events and we either create or update the document. We noticed that we are creating duplicate documents if we get two events within few milliseconds. The first event should result into new document and the second one should be an update.

Here is the logic that we have in the stored prod.

1. Look for an existing document with the specific Id and status
2. Create a new document or update an existing document if it exist.
3. If create, we do a select one more time to check if we have only one document with the combination of id and status. If more than 1, rollback. In case of update, we rely on the Etag.

We are good with the update but create is giving us hard time. Let me know if there is a way we can fix it. 
Deduplicate key is the combination of external id and status. We have an existing database and we want to avoid any change that requires creating a new database.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: which consistency level are you using?

Comment: Consistent prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a [unique key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys). CosmosDB will prevent the insertion of duplicate keys that are designated unique. You can then catch the exception and perform your update logic.

**Edit based on feedback**

I'm assuming you're in an environment where more than one thread or process is executing this logic. You're going to need a critical section (a lock) when you try to process each document. When it comes time to interact with CosmosDB, you'll need to acquire a lock on the id of the document you're going to insert/update. You can then check to see if the document exists, and do your insert or update based on the result. Then you'll exit the critical section by releasing the lock.

Depending on what technologies you're using will dictate what is available for you. If it's a single instance of an Azure Function, you can use something like a static ThreadSafeDictionary for locking. If it's multiple Azure Functions or Web Apps, you'll need a distributed lock. There are several ways to do this, such as Azure Blob Leases.

I am unaware of any type of synchronization functionality available OOTB in CosmosDB.

Comment: Thank you Rob, we have an existing database and we want to avoid creating a new one with unique constraint. This will be a significant effort. I missed this part in the question.

Comment: @RohitRanjan I've elaborated on my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate your time Rob, unfortunately any critical section will kill the scalability and performance. We are using service fabric. This service is hosted on multiple clusters across geo location.

Comment: Critical sections will be on a per-id basis under that strategy. So your locking will be minimal.